# How to set order of DateTime components while also providing CultureInfo

Tags: c#, datetime, format, datetimeoffset

I have a `DateTimeOffset` and want to display it like this for `en-GB`

```
23/08/2020 09:00
```

or for `en-US`:

```
08/23/2020 09:00
```

but when I do

```
dateTimeOffset.DateTime.ToString(new CultureInfo("en-GB"));
```

It gives me the following (I don't want it to show AM/PM):

```
23/08/2020 09:00 AM
```

I know I can do `ToString("dd/MM/yyy HH:mm")`, but then the format would be wrong for US culture

Answer (score 1):

```
            var date = new DateTime(2020, 8, 23, 9, 0, 0);
            var gbFmt = string.Format(new CultureInfo("en-gb"), "{0:d} {0:HH:mm}", date);
            var usFmt = string.Format(new CultureInfo("en-us"), "{0:d} {0:HH:mm}", date);
            Console.Write("gb: {0}\nus: {1}\n", gbFmt, usFmt);

            /*   gb: 23/08/2020 09:00
                 us:  8/23/2020 09:00    */
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it like this, using [CultureInfo.DateTimeFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.datetimeformat?view=net-5.0)

```
var shortDatePattern = _culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;
var formatString = dateTimeOffset.ToString($"{shortDatePattern} HH:mm");
```